# How to take 'url' variable from this JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, string, api, url

How can I print out content of "url" from this JSON string.

```
[{"breeds":[],"id":"bkv","url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/bkv.jpg","width":800,"height":600}]
```

I want to just print that in my python console. That JSON is from https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search if it matters.

```
    response = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search')
x = response.json()
json_obj = json.loads(x)
for i in json_obj:
    print(i["url"])
```

Comment: Could you give more details / context please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are multiple JSON elements inside your JSON string:

```
import json
json_string = '[{"breeds":[],"id":"bkv","url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/bkv.jpg","width":800,"height":600}]'
json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
for i in json_obj:
    print(i["url"])
```

If you want to directly receive the JSON from the URL, you can do this directly:

```
import requests
for i in requests.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").json():
    print(i["url"])
```

Comment: response = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search')
    x = response.json()
    json_obj = json.loads(x)
    for i in json_obj:
        print(i["url"])

I get: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: You don't need to do json.load after you already received the json object. I did it to convert the string into json. You can see the edited answer for requests. @EloBenc

Comment: Thank you! That second bit of code worked!

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted. @EloBenc

Comment: I will do it as soon as i can :D 4 minutes to go.

Comment: If i do the same thing with https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random and replace "url" with "message" it doesn't work; TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: For that url, it doesn't return an array. You can directly do `requests.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random").json()["message"]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {"breeds":[],"id":"bkv","url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/bkv.jpg","width":800,"height":600}
print(data["url"])
```

or

```
print(data.values()[2])
```

Does one of these two work? If not, may i see the full code that you have for this problem (if this isn't everything)

Hope it works